# how to make jquery functions like lightbox and others work on a page called using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is what I want.
*I created a page to show some departments. Using $('.getDetails').click(), employers of each department will be listed with some of their details. And on clicking the employer name mini profile of employer will be displayed too.*   This is the code I used to list the employers

```
$('.getDetails').click(function(e) {
    var department = $('.getDepartment').val();
    var month = $('.month').val();
    $.ajax({
        data: 'dept='+department+'&month='+month,
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=(site_url('admin/employer/getAttendanceDetails.php'))?>",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $('.attendance_display').html( html );
    });
});
```

in the page **getAttendanceDetails.php** I am want a lightbox using this code

```
<input type="button" id="show-profile-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show User Profile">
<div id="show-profile" class="">
    <div class="profile-inner">
    Show this div as lightbox
    </div>
</div>
```

The lightbox is working in the main page, but it is not working in page called using ajax.
Can anyone help me to find a solution to this problem?

UPDATED

This is the jquery function

```
    if( $.fn.dialog ) {
        $("#show-profile-btn").bind("click", function (event) {
            $("#show-profile").dialog("option", {
                modal: false
            }).dialog("open");
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#show-profile-btn").bind("click", function (event) {
            $("#show-profile").dialog("option", {
                modal: true
            }).dialog("open");
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#show-profile-btn").bind("click", function (event) {
            $("#show-profile").dialog("option", {
                modal: true
            }).dialog("open");
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You should post your full `controller` and `view` code.

Comment: I think i got where the problem is you just need to reinitialise lightbox function after you get thae ajax data.Can i see the code of your js how you call that lightbox.??

Comment: @NishantLad I had updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Have you tried live in place of bind you can also use on method

Comment: yes, I tried both. But, still not working.

Comment: Have you tried my answer below? It should work for you - it worked for me when tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example.

Here is your main page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.getDetails').click(function(e) {
                    var department = $('.getDepartment').val();
                    var month = $('.month').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        data: 'dept='+department+'&month='+month,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'getAttendanceDetails.php',
                        context: document.body,
                        success: function(data) {
                            //alert(data);
                            $('.attendance_display').html( data );
                            $('.attendance_display').dialog( 'open' );
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END ajax call
                }); //END getDetails.click() fn

            $( ".attendance_display" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                title: 'The Ax Response:',
                buttons: {
                    'I know': function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        alert('How nice for you');
                    },
                    'Close now': function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            }); //END attendance_display dlg init

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Inside the yellow div are two hidden input fields,<br>
    but they could be anything at all, from visible<br>
    input fields to dropdown (select) controls, to<br>
    something else....<br>
    <br>
    <div class="getDetails" style="width:300px; background:yellow;">
        CLICK ANYWHERE IN THIS DIV TO SEE RESPONSE:<br>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" class="getDepartment" value="Physics">
        <input type="hidden" class="month" value="October">
    </div>

    <div class="attendance_display"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

And here is your getAttendanceDetails.php AJAX responder:

```
<?php

$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$mon = $_POST['month'];

echo 'You were enrolled in the [' .$dept. '] department in the month of [' .$mon. ']';
```

Comment: Yes @gibberish. It worked. Thanks Buddy.. 
But there is a little bit change in my case. 
I will post code below.

Comment: But your answer seems to be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Code in Main Page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.getDetails').click(function(e) {
                var department = $('.getDepartment').val();
                var month = $('.month').val();
                $.ajax({
                    data: 'dept='+department+'&month='+month,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'getAttendanceDetails.php',
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //alert(data);
                        $('.attendance_show').html( data );
                    //    $('.attendance_display').dialog( 'open' );
                    } //END success fn
                }); //END ajax call
            }); //END getDetails.click() fn

        $( ".attendance_display" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 250,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            title: 'The Ax Response:',
            buttons: {
                'I know': function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    alert('How nice for you');
                },
                'Close now': function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        }); //END attendance_display dlg init

        }); //END $(document).ready()

    </script>
</head>
```

```
Inside the yellow div are two hidden input fields,<br>
but they could be anything at all, from visible<br>
input fields to dropdown (select) controls, to<br>
something else....<br>
<br>
<div class="getDetails" style="width:300px; background:yellow;">
    CLICK ANYWHERE IN THIS DIV TO SEE RESPONSE:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" class="getDepartment" value="Physics">
    <input type="hidden" class="month" value="October">
</div>

<div class="attendance_show"></div>
```

Code of Page to be called.

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ClickmeNow').click(function(e){
        $('.attendance_display').dialog( 'open' );
    });
            $( ".attendance_display" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                title: 'The Ax Response:',
                buttons: {
                    'I know': function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        alert('How nice for you');
                    },
                    'Close now': function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            }); //END attendance_display dlg init
});

</script>
<style>
.ClickmeNow {
color:#063;
}
</style>
<table> 
<?php for( $i = 1;$i < 5; $i++ ): ?>
    <tr> 
        <td> Name <?=$i?> </td> 
        <td> Detail 1 </td>
        <td> Detail 2 </td>
        <td> Detail 3 </td>
        <td> <a class="ClickmeNow" alt="Page2Load"> View </a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
    <div class="attendance_display"></div>

<?php

$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$mon = $_POST['month'];

echo 'You were enrolled in the [' .$dept. '] department in the month of [' .$mon. ']'; 
echo '<input type="button" class="clickMe" value="Dialog Box" />';
```